# Dr. Strangelove or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb

Tags: knowledge, movies, code

Can you recover the following two dozens of (well-known) movie titles just from their initials?

```
    1. FWAAF   
    2. TGTBATU 
    3. BOTFOJ
    4. IJATTOD 
    5. WEHTBJ  
    6. HPATPOA 
    7. OFOTCN  
    8. HISTK   
    9. BCATSK    
   10. TWOO      
   11. MPATHG  
   12. TSOTL  

   13. SM   
   14. LEDP  
   15. OBWAT   
   16. TBOTRK  
   17. LAC     
   18. CK      
   19. NCFOM   
   20. TDCOTB  
   21. MIGP    
   22. FMJ     
   23. CATCF   
   24. MSGTW
```

Example:
DSOHILTSWALTB = "Dr. Strangelove or How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb"

Comment: All I can think of for number 18 is Calvin Klein.

Comment: Since movies 13 and 20 have been solved last, I count them as the most difficult one of the 24 questions and I assign the "correct answer" sign to them.

Comment: @Martin Whatt???
I was thinking there should be a community wiki to compile all the answers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Number 13 is

> Slumdog Millionaire

Number 20 is

> The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie
>  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Discreet_Charm_of_the_Bourgeoisie

Answer (score 6):

## [Community wiki]: The results of a collaboration by The Dragonista, Haobin, Marmy1954 and Gamow:

Number 1:

> FWAAF = Four Weddings and a Funeral

Number 2:

> TGTBATU = The Good, the Bad and the Ugly

Number 3:

> BOTFOJ = Born on the Fourth of July

Number 4:

> IJATTOD = Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom

Number 5:

> WEHTBJ = What Ever Happened to Baby Jane

Number 6:

> HPATPOA = Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

Number 7:

> OFOTCN = One Flew Over the Cuckoo's Nest

Number 8:

> HISTK = Honey, I Shrunk the Kids

Number 9:

> BCATSK = Butch Cassidy and the Sundance Kid

Number 10:

> TWOO = The Wizard of Oz

Number 11:

> MPATHG =  Monty Python and the Holy Grail

Number 12:

> TSOTL = The Silence of the Lambs

Number 13:

> SM = Slumdog Millionaire

Number 14:

> LEDP = Les Enfants du Paradis

Number 15:

> OBWAT = O Brother, Where Art Thou?

Number 16:

> TBOTRK = The Bridge On The River Kwai

Number 17:

> LAC = L.A. Confidential

Number 18:

> CK = Citizen Kane

Number 19:

> NCFOM = No Country for Old Men

Number 20:

> TDCOTB = The Discreet Charm of the Bourgeoisie

Number 21:

> MIGP= Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol

Number 22:

> FMJ = Full Metal Jacket

Number 23:

> CATCF = Charlie and the Chocolate Factory

Number 24:

> MSGTW = Mr. Smith Goes to Washington

Answer (score 4):

Number 13

> SM=Silas Marner

Number 21

> MIGP= Mission: Impossible - Ghost Protocol

that's all I have

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: It provides an answer to number 13.  old movie Silas Marner, like the book.

Answer (score 3):

Number 4:

> IJATTOD = Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom

Number 6:

> HPATPOA = Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban

Number 17:

> LAC = L.A. Confidential

Number 22:

> FMJ = Full Metal Jacket